# c++/cli check if value is number

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++-cli

I've made a windows form application with 3 text boxes.For the program to work, I need all the three boxes to be filled with a number.They can be positive or negative.

I used this:

```
if(this->textBox1->Text=="" || this->textBox2->Text=="" || this->textBox3->Text=="") {
    MessageBox::Show("Error");
}
else {
    // continue with the program...
}
```

to check if the boxes are filled, but I can't figure out how to display error message if there is a symbol like a letter or something else, different from a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you actually want to do something with the numbers?

So test for conversion failure:

```
int number1;
if (!int::TryParse(textBox1->Text, number1)) {
    MessageBox::Show("First box wasn't an integer");
    return;
}

double number2;
if (!double::TryParse(textBox2->Text, number2)) {
    MessageBox::Show("Second box wasn't numeric");
    return;
}
```

At the end, you have the numbers `number1` and `number2` to use in your calculation.

You won't need a separate test for empty string anymore, since `TryParse` will return false if the input is empty.

Comment: Thanks.
This works with int, but I get error with double, when I enter something like 2.5

Comment: @user2765257: I've used `TryParse` for doubles before without issue, so I suggest you look at your code again, you might not be converting what you think you are.

Comment: So this is where I get the error:
'number = System::Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1->Text);'
TryParse passes this number, but the program breaks when I try to convert it.

Comment: @user2765257: Don't use `Convert::ToInt32`.  You already got the value from `TryParse`.  As for your error, it's because after `double::TryParse`, you should use `double::Parse` or `Convert::ToDouble`, not `Convert::ToInt32`.  But what's the point of converting a second time?

Comment: Oh yes, you said that in the first place, but I didn't get it. :)
Works great now.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Double.TryParse()`:

```
Double x;
array<TextBox^>^ inputs = gcnew array<TextBox^>(3);
inputs[0] = this->textBox1;
inputs[1] = this->textBox2;
inputs[2] = this->textBox3;

for (int i = 0; i < inputs->Length; i++)
{
    if(!Double::TryParse(inputs[i]->Text, x))
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Error", String::Format("Cannot parse textBox{0} as number", i+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: C# syntax leaking into your C++?